# Confused about bridge entities & multi-attribute entities

Tags: mysql, sql, database, create-table

I just have a few questions which I am confused about. I couldn't get my er-diagram to show up on this post, so I had to create a "text" version of it.

```
Entity: customers
    Attributes: 
                cus_id -- primary key
                cus_fname -- multi-attribute (name)
                cus_lname -- multi-attribute (name)
                cus_gender -- multi-attribute (name)
                cus_dob

Entity: products
    Attributes:
                prod_id -- primary key
                prod_name
                prod_cost
                prod_retail

Bridge Entity: buys
    Attributes:
                prod_id
                cus_id
---------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE customers (
    cus_id        NUMBER(5,0)
                  CONSTRAINT cus_id_pk
                  PRIMARY KEY (cus_id),
    cus_fname     VARCHAR2(32),
    cus_mname     VARCHAR2(32),
    cus_lname     VARCHAR2(32),
    cus_gender    NUMBER(1,0),
    cus_dob       DATE
);
-----------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE products (
    prod_id       NUMBER(5,0)
                  CONSTRAINT cus_id_pk
                  PRIMARY KEY (cus_id),
    prod_name     VARCHAR2(32),
    prod_cost     NUMBER(4,2),
    prod_retail   NUMBER(4,2)
);
```

1. How do I create a bridge entity? So my bridge entity is called buys, how would I make that? I looked online, but all I see is select statements.

2. How would I create a multi-valued attribute? Like the customer's name, that is a multi-valued attribute
3. Should I also include the NOT NULL in the primary keys? I am thinking about adding a NOT NULL to the customer's names.

Answer (score 0):

`buys` is called an association table, or a join table, a relationship table, or any other number of names.  I wouldn't refer to it as an "entity" unless it truly is an entity in your system (represents a person, place, thing concept or event, which can be uniquely identified, is of interest to the business, and we can store information about.)

Table definition for an association table might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE buys
( prod_id  NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL COMMENT 'composite PK, FK ref products.prod_id'
, cus_id   NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL COMMENT 'composite PK, FK ref customers.cus_id'
, PRIMARY KEY (prod_id, cus_id) 
, UNIQUE KEY buys_UX1 (cus_id, prod_id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_buys_products FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES products (prod_id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE     
, CONSTRAINT FK_buys_customers FOREIGN KEY (cus_id) REFERENCES customers (cus_id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE     
) ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Note: I don't believe `NUMBER(5,0)` is a valid MySQL datatype. For primary key columns, I tend to use an integer datatype, `INT` or `BIGINT`. But Foreign key columns must match the datatype of the referenced primary columns EXACTLY, so I've used `NUMBER(5,0)` as a copy of the datatype of the referenced columns.

---

A multi-valued attribute can be implemented as a child table, one to many relationship. But I don't see any indication of a multi-valued attribute in the model.

A composite attribute could be implemented as a separate table. But I wouldn't go there, unless there was a use-case that made that advantageous.

My personal preference for handling composite attributes would be to simply prefix the column names. For example, as an indication that these columns are components of a attribute "name" ...

```
 cus_name_title
 cus_name_last
 cus_name_first
 cus_name_suffix
```

Similarly, for an "mailing address" attribute

```
cus_addr_street
cus_addr_line2
cus_addr_city
cus_addr_state
cus_addr_postal_code
```

(Some other relational database support declaring composite "types"; I don't believe this feature is available in MySQL. (And I wouldn't choose to represent a composite attribute as a JSON object.)

The `PRIMARY KEY` constraint already enforces NOT NULL on all of the columns in the primary key. But it doesn't hurt to also explicitly include the `NOT NULL` constraint. My preference is to add the `NOT NULL` constraint on any column where we do not want to accept NULL values.

**FOLLOWUP**

For multi-valued attributes of an entity (an attribute that can have zero, one or more values, for a single instance), a common pattern is a child table.
Take as an example, customer phone number.

We can create table with a foreign key, referencing the cus_id in customers.

```
 CREATE TABLE cus_phone_numbers 
 ( id            INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'PK'
 , cus_id        NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref customers.cus_id'
 , phone_type    VARCHAR(80)  COMMENT 'e.g. main, mobile, office, fax'
 , phone_number  VARCHAR(80)
 , CONSTRAINT FK_cus_phone_numbers_customers 
   FOREIGN KEY (cus_id) REFERENCES customers (cus_id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB 
 ;
```

As an example, a customer with three phone numbers would have three rows in the phone numbers table.  A customer with no phone number would have zero rows in the table.

```
  cus_id   phone_type    phone_number
  ------   ----------    ---------------
      42   main 1        xxx-xxx-1111
      42   office        xxx-xxx-1212
      42   fax           xxx-xxx-3333
     112   service       xxx-xxx-7701
     112   delivery      xxx-xxx-7702
```

That is *multi-valued* attributes... and attribute of an entity that can have zero, one or more values.

---

A *composite* attribute is made up by several component attributes. For example, a customers "name" attribute can be a combination of several simple attributes:

```
 title/salutation        'Major'
 first name              'Charles'
 middle name             'Emerson'
 last name               'Winchester'
 suffix                  'III'
 nickname                ''
```

It's always possible to split out some attributes of an entity into a separate table(s), whether those are simple or composite attributes. One of the most common reasons we do that is to support multiple values. But we can also do that for single-value attributes.

Consider the "phone number" attribute. That could be modeled as a composite attribute:

```
country code        +1
area code           888
exchange number     467
line number         4355
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was super helpful. I just have one question. You said for multi-valued attributes I should create a child table. What do you mean by that? How would I create a child table and link it to the main table. So for my diagram, `cus_fname` (firstname), `cus_mname` (middle name) and `cus_lname` (last name) are the multi-valued attributes that should be in the customer table

Comment: A *multi-valued* attribute can be either simple or composite. A *composite* attribute is not necessarily multi-valued. A composite attribute is made up of other attributes.  Customer "name" is a composite attribute. Let's assign "cus_name" as the name of the composite attribute. That won't be a column name in the table, we will have columns for the components. If we follow the fname, lname, mname convention that you've proposed, then I would name the columns `cus_name_fname`, `cus_name_lname`, `cus_name_mname`.  The common prefix `cus_name_` indicates these columns are components.